# Haskell installation on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, haskell, ghc, chocolatey

I try to install Haskell with chcolatey. When I run `choco install ghc` it downloads ghc as expected. But at some point it says this:

```
Access to the path 'C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32' is denied.
Renamed C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32 to C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1
ERROR: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\tools\ghc-9.0.1\bin\ghcii.sh'.
The install of ghc was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
See log for details.
```

I run this command in the Windows PowerShell as Administrator, so why he can't access this folder?
Im using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!!!
My Antivirus-Software blocked the access. I just deactivated it for the time of the installation and it worked fine.

Comment: You may also find that every invocation of GHC causes the antivirus to scan the executable because its not signed. You might have to add the installation folder to some kind of whitelist to get decent compilation speed. This matters because the "cabal" and "stack" tools you will be using for any non-trivial project invoke GHC for each module.